# Прокрутка с изменением opacity элемента

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте. Подскажите. Имеется меню у сайта в самом верху. Оно имеет свойство position:fixed; Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке элемента он сохранял фиксированную позицию, но становился прозрачнее. При возвращении на самый верх сайта приобретал опять opacity:1; Заранее Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте jQuery.

Вот, как вариант, посмотрите **[здесь](http://webcomplex.com.ua/jquery/delaem-fiksirovannoe-menyu-pri-prokrutke-stranicy.html)**. Стили заточите под свои потребности.

Удачи

---

Если не подойдет - Google в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

так пойдет ? http://jsfiddle.net/zStXH/6/